# How to change the Pycharm interpreter to use Anaconda?

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

When I run `python --version` in my terminal, it says I have Python 3.7.1 - supposedly because I have Anaconda installed. However, Pycharm does not recognize this under the Project Interpreter tab.

Instead of installing basically the same version from Python.org and have it install another shell and take up space(with the assumption that Pycharm would recognize this), is there a way for Pycharm to recognize the currently installed version?

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's just obvious to me because I know that Anaconda is based on conda, but above your selected "system interpreter" there is a "conda environment" which is (very likely) what you need. You may need to additionally configure the conda environments if PyCharm doesn't auto-detect these (but that should be as easy as adding the folder where the environment is stored in the PyCharm settings).

Comment: @MSeifert is there a way to just access the Python version that is stored within Anaconda? I am not looking to use Anaconda packages within Pycharm (not the Conda environment) - just for an alternative to installing the Python IDE.

Comment: Have you looked at the duplicates I provided? PyCharm just needs the path to the python executable. If it's a conda environment or a system installation shouldn't matter. That these are separate in PyCharm is so PyCharm knows how to install packages if you need that).

Comment: Ok. I selected an executable within anaconda - /anadonca3/bin/python to be exact and Pycharm seems to be loading it.